# How do you define a Dashboard view in Jenkins Job Builder

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-builder

First, I would settle for a good example of a simple view definition in Jenkins Job Builder. The documentation seems woefully inadequate.

All I can find is this (which is two sentences with an incomplete example)

https://docs.openstack.org/infra/jenkins-job-builder/definition.html?highlight=view#views

But, what I really want to know is if it is possible to define a Dashboard view (https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Dashboard+View) via Jenkins Job Builder. I can't find anything that says you can, so I assume it is not possible. But, as mentioned before, the documentation on defining views is so sparse I can't be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps exploring the following part of Jenkins' `config.xml` helps:

```
  <views>
    ...
    <hudson.plugins.view.dashboard.Dashboard plugin="dashboard-view@2.9.11">
      ...
      <name>My Dashboard</name>
      ...
    </hudson.plugins.view.dashboard.Dashboard>
    ...
  </views>
```

I guess the list names in YAML are the same as the element names in XML.

However, there's a counterpart to Jenkins Job Builder: [Jenkins View Builder](https://www.unixdaemon.net/tools/trying-jenkins-view-builder/).

Comment: The reference to Jenkins View Builder at least addressed my the first part of my question as it contained a good example of a simple view definition. Even though it was for Jenkins View Builder, I figured that Jenkins Job Builder would accept the same syntax and it did.
Any idea why someone would use Jenkins View Builder when Jenkins Job Builder supports views?

Comment: That only worked a little. At this point, I am going to assume that the view definitions in JJB are either incomplete or just completely non-functional.

I can't even get a simple example to work.

Comment: So, I gave up on JJB and started using JVB. It appears to be more functional than the view support in JJB.
Although, it also does not support Dashboard views. But, there is at least pledged support.

Comment: Alas, JJB requires pbr module version < 2.0 and JVB requires the pbr module version > 2.0. So, the two don't play nice together.

Answer (score 0):

From Jenkins Job Builder source code only "List" and "Pipeline" view types are available.

If you need you can use raw xml feature of JJB:
[Raw config](https://docs.openstack.org/infra/jenkins-job-builder/definition.html#raw-config)

Just create Dashboard view via Jenkins WEB UI and copy definition of this view from Jenkins's config.xml (/var/lib/jenkins/config.xml)